# where in syntax

Tags: soql

I am looking for the where in syntax for raw soql.

I try:

```
SELECT ID, OWNDERID FROM Opportunity where OwnerID in {'005G0000002eMbxIAE'};
```

and

```
SELECT ID, OWNDERID FROM Opportunity where OwnerID in '005G0000002eMbxIAE';
```

Neither work. Any tips?

Comment: Please tell us the `OWNDERID` is just a typo made here and not in the original queries ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With just one id, you should just do:

```
SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Opportunity where OwnerID = '005G0000002eMbxIAE';
```

But if you are doing multiple ids, you can do in with:

```
SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Opportunity where OwnerID in ('005G0000002eMbxIAE', '005G0000002eMbxIAE');
```

Or you can pass a list:

```
List<Id> ownerIds = ...
SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Opportunity where OwnerID in :ownerIds;
```